# What is the most effective least toxic thing to kill dog ticks?

Tags: pest-control

i wonder whether you smart people can help. I've semi adopted a cute fluffy dog in SE Asia and it's Man vs Dog tick, and the ticks are winning big time.

The problem is that the place is full of street dogs so the ticks are always there to be picked up. Used Raid in the apartment, which i guess works for the rooms but doesn't always kill the ticks unless you smother them with it. Will it kill the eggs and larvae? 
Tried smothering him in lemongrass juice yesterday but some ticks just walked right through that.

Any ideas for him and the home?

Thanks

Comment: I am not a vet (or someone in any way qualified to answer), I'm just a dog owner. There are medications for that such as [Revolution](http://www.revolution4dogs.com/) for example. They are not very expensive and pretty effective to my personal experience. Do you have any reason for considering lemongrass juice rather than these medications? Do you have any reason to think these medications are toxic for your dog or are they too expensive? (you might want to address these questions in your pets.SE post).

Answer (score -1):

Two remedies I've seen elsewhere:

1. Vaseline, or mineral oil.  Coat the tick.
2. The end of a lit cigarette or incense stick. Don't touch the tick, just near by.  The heat causes it to let go.

A somewhat slower method that may work -- works on cockroaches -- boric acid crystals.  Dust on and brush thoroughly.  The crystals abrade the wax on the outer chiton, and they dehydrate.  Harmless when ingested.

Ticks rarely transfer from animal to animal.  The usual way at least here in Canada is they will climb a stem of tall grass or weed then make their transfer when brushed by an animal or bird.  When full they drop off, do their egg thing, and then find another stem for another go.

See if you end up with fewer ticks if you give your dog a good brushing right after he's been to the park or other vegetated area.